# How to do Spring Boot Admin Hystrix-Dashboard Integration

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, spring-boot-admin

Not able to integrate Hystrix Dashboard with Spring Boot Admin

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

I have followed the instructions as given in http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.3/#_hystrix_ui_module.

I have added the spring boot admin client and hystrix dependency in my client and used @EnableHystrix and put @HystricCommand on my endpoints but i'm not able to see hystrix streams in the Spring Boot Admin UI.

What am i missing?

Can anyone please tell me the proper steps, if i am missing something.

Adding client pom:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.demo.client</groupId>
<artifactId>democlient</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>democlient</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Client Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableHystrix
public class DemoClient {

public static void main(String[] Args) {

SpringApplication.run(DemoClient.class, Args);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
@HystrixCommand
public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {

  return new ResponseEntity<String>("Client Test", HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Admin application.properties:

```
spring.boot.admin.routes.endpoints= env,metrics,trace,dump,jolokia,info,configprops,trace,logfile,refresh,flyway,liquibase,heapdump,hystrix.stream,turbine.stream
```

Client application.properties:

```
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8080
spring.boot.admin.auto-registration= true
spring.boot.admin.auto-deregistration = true
```

After running the application the endpoints do get registered as per logs in Admin Server but i get following warning and i cannot see the hystrix stream in the Admin UI.
Admin logs:

```
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-8] d.c.b.a.registry.ApplicationRegistry     [register:81] : New Application Application [id=8e14fbfe, name=democlient, managementUrl=http://localhost:8086, healthUrl=http://localhost:8086/health, serviceUrl=http://localhost:8086] registered
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/health/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/env/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/metrics/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/trace/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/dump/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/jolokia/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/info/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/configprops/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/logfile/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/refresh/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/flyway/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/liquibase/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/heapdump/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/hystrix.stream/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
INFO 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      [registerHandler:354] : Mapped URL path [/api/applications/8e14fbfe/turbine.stream/**] onto handler of type [class de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController]
WARN 15220 --- [nio-8245-exec-2] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   [run:70] : Error during filtering

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117)
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:349)
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:311)
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:186)
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120)
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43)
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.zuul.OptionsDispatchingZuulController.handleRequest(OptionsDispatchingZuulController.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Client logs:

```
INFO 6764 --- [gistrationTask1] d.c.b.a.services.ApplicationRegistrator  [register:82] : Application registered itself as {managementUrl=http://localhost:8086, healthUrl=http://localhost:8086/health, serviceUrl=http://localhost:8086, name=democlient, id=8e14fbfe, statusInfo={status=UNKNOWN, timestamp=1477856166713}}
WARN 6764 --- [nio-8248-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             [handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported:215] : Request method 'HEAD' not supported
```

Comment: Did you add the hystrix.stream endpoint to the spring.boot.admin.routes.endpoints in the admin server as described in the docs?

Comment: @joshiste yes i added, but the key name is spring.boot.admin.routes.routes in spring boot 1.4 and i added all the endpoints as in the docs. Like this:- spring.boot.admin.routes.routes=env,metrics,trace,dump,jolokia,info,configprops,trace,logfile,refresh,flyway,liquibase,heapdump,hystrix.stream,turbine.stream

Comment: no it's `spring.boot.admin.routes.endpoints`

Comment: @joshiste but when i add spring.boot.admin.routes.endpoints in application.properties a warning comes that this property doesn't exist (i'm using STS).I have tried putting both keys with same values but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: that's an error in the metadata. I filed an issue for that: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/309#

Comment: @joshiste So is there a workaround until it's fixed?

Comment: You don't need one since it is just documentary. Live with the warning

Comment: @joshiste but even when i add spring.boot.admin.routes.endpoints=env,metrics,trace,dump,jolok‌​ia,info,configprops,‌​trace,logfile,refres‌​h,flyway,liquibase,h‌​eapdump,hystrix.stre‌​am,turbine.stream i'm still not able to see hytrix streams in Admin UI. What else am i missing?

Comment: @joshiste i have added the client code also and added logs also in which it's shown that hystrix.stream is registered but i still cannot see the hystrix stream in admin ui and there is also a warning that comes. Can you please check and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @joshiste I have added client log too, in that also i get a warning and why is status UNKNOWN in statsuinfo?

Comment: When the application is registered state is unknown, direct after registration the StatusUpdater should update it to UP.

Comment: I can't see any error. Did you check that the hystrix.stream on the client is reachable for the admin server?

Comment: @joshiste Thanks for reply. Yes hystrix.stream on the client is reachable but i cannot see the stream in the admin server. i can open the stream in another hystrix dashboard application without any problem but i cannot see the same in admin server and what are the warnings in both client and server.

Comment: @joshiste Hi did you find any error in the above settings?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and solved with updates.

It shows up that the problem was `spring-cloud-dependencies` version (**Camden RT**) on client, which had some problems showing `/hystrix.stream` (mentioned [here](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/351)).

Upgrading to **Dalston RT** solved issue with `/hystrix.stream` accessibility (sidenote - for hystrix functionality on Feign, you must enable it explicitly via `feign.hystrix.enabled=true`, took some time to discover) . Since SBA `1.5.x` relies on **Dalston**, I also upgraded SBA to `1.5.4` on server.

Now I can access SBAS with dynamically resolved hystrix board.

Hope someone may benefit from this answer.

Comment: Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444872/org-springframework-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard-hystrixdashboardconfiguratio ?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you dont see direclty the Hystrix tab in your application page in Spring Boot Admin Server (SBAS), you have to go to the application page (from SBAS) and access directly (e.g http://localhost:8080/#/applications/f78fi52c/hystrix).

i think that's what [@joshiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5834477/joshiste) tried to clear when he say : *check that the hystrix.stream on the client is reachable for the admin server*

Later, you will see the hystrix tab
[Application page in SBAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pssA.png)

Another thing, before checking the Hystrix tab make some requests in the client (which implement Hystrix) for some metrics

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: after upgrading from Spring Boot 1.x to 2.x my Hystrix Dashboard disappeared from Spring Boot Admin. Turns out Hystrix Dashboard was [dropped](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.1.6/#_changes_with_2_x) in Spring Boot Admin 2. I've written a [Q&A on how to get it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929693/how-to-get-hystrix-dashboard-working-again-in-spring-boot-admin-2-x).