# How to get Hystrix Dashboard working again in Spring Boot Admin 2.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin, hystrix-dashboard

Spring Boot Admin 1 has an integrated [Hystrix Dashboard](https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/hystrix-dashboard/). After upgrading my stack from Spring Boot 1.x to 2.x; this dashboard seems to have disappeared. How can I re-enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official support for Hystrix Dashboard was [dropped](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.1.6/#_changes_with_2_x) in Spring Boot Admin 2.x. There now exists an [unofficial plugin](https://github.com/MartinDevillers/spring-boot-admin-hystrix-dashboard) for Spring Boot Admin 2.x that brings Hystrix Dashboard back to live.

Add the following Maven dependency to your Spring Boot Admin application's `pom.xml`, rebuild and deploy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nl.devillers</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The instance view in Spring Boot Admin should now show a "Hystrix" tab with the dashboard, like in the screenshot below. If it doesn't show up, make sure your Spring Boot application (the client) is properly configured:

- The `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` property includes the `hystrix.stream` endpoint (or `*` for all endpoints)
- The application is annotated with the `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.EnableHystrix` annotation from the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix` package

[image: Screenshot of Hystrix Dashboard in Spring Boot Admin]