# org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.HystrixDashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet.doGet - Spring Cloud Turbine Streams

Tags: hystrix, turbine, hystrix-dashboard

I'm working on `Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE + Eureka + Cloud Config + Hystrix + Turbine` Example. Insipration from the https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=771ae7a6-e2eb-465a-b7ea-99c8a5531a43.

In this example, I'm looking to aggregate the metrics from different services into single `Hystrix` Dashboard using Turbine Streams.

Error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:276) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:294) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:207) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:679) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:481) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar!/:4.5.12]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.HystrixDashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet.doGet(HystrixDashboardConfiguration.java:177) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

I've uploaded complete code here: https://github.com/JavaNeed/spring-cloud-hystrix-turbine-aggregate.git.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

@Ash_P I was able to get the dashboard running fine for the code you put up for `http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=TOLLRATE-BILLBOARD`

[image: Working Dashboard]

Issue number 1: 
Please check if `@EnableTurbine` annotation is present in `CoHystrixDashboardApplication`
 as in the repository shared, it was commented. Without this basic switch on the dashboard, your dashoard will not be able to consume the turbine stream

```
@EnableTurbine
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoHystrixDashboardApplication
```

Issue number 2:
Check if rabbit-mq is running in the background. Use docker to simplify this:

```
docker run -d --hostname local-rabbit --name test-rmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3.6.9-management
```

Please check and let me know if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Can you please try to give http://localhost:8087 in the hystrix URL and see if its gathers metrix ? I am looking for that fix

Comment: Hey, its a turbine Project (co-hystrix-turbine) which will collect all the metrics stream data and show on to the single dashbaord

Comment: Did you get chance to look at the exact issue ?

Comment: I didn't get a lot of time to look into it, I was however able to get it working when everything had spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.5.4.RELEASE and spring-cloud.version Dalston.SR1, versions being very important here, any mismatch would result in streams not working as expected.  You can do this confirm if the services are streaming to rabbit and http://localhost:8087/ shows up data and not just pings. You should first get these things sorted.

Comment: Hey, I know this code works well for `1.5.4.RELEASE` & `Dalston.SR1`, when using Spring Boot `v2.2.6.RELEASE`, using `Spring Cloud version Hoxton.SR3`, I do see when I see Exchange, data is coming there in RabbitMQ, but not sure why its not showing over integrated Hystrix Dashboard. You're right, its could be because of mismatch of versions, but how cab we make this working ?